# WPF ItemControl: restrict the type of the item to a specific one

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I'm creating as an exercise a WPF custom control to display log messages as in the VS panel (Errors/Warnings/Message). The control is an ItemControl, every item is a message to display. But I have to classify the message in the proper category, so I need each item to expose something ( an interface maybe ) to let the control know how to categorizxe the message. I don't know how to force the Item to be of a certain type, how can I achieve this ?
Is the design startegy wrong ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can inherit your custom control from ItemsControl and create a strongly typed collectional property, then in your control's template put the following line:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MyStronglyTypedCollectionalPropertyName}" />
```

I do it a lot with ObservableCollections.

The fact that you use ItemsControl doesn't oblige you to use its ItemsSource directly, you can bind to it instead.

P.S. Technically speaking that still leaves a possibility for anyone to go off and set ItemsSource directly bypassing MyStronglyTypedCollectionalPropertyName. Personally I don't think that it's a good idea to throw in that case, but you can check the value type from within OnPropertyChanged:

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgse) 
{   

   if (e.Property == ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty && e.NewValue as MySuperTime == null)
   { 

      throw new ArgumentException("ItemsSource value must be of 'MySuperTime' type.");
   }

   base.OnPropertyChanged(e); 

}
```

Comment: Doesn't this still allow you to not set `ItemsSource`, then manually shove anything in the `Items` collection directly? In my case, I overrode `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` and throw the exception there if any item isn't the type I expect.  This covers both cases, albeit in a roundabout way.